# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - how to get path to Jenkinsfile in use?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We have a series of Jenkinsfile scripts which are identical, except each configures an environment item to point to the directory in the SCM checkout that holds the Jenkinsfile. That is used to reference a file in the same directory. The SCM repo has all of these Jenkinsfile scripts in different directories. I see an easy opening to make the pipeline script identical in each case if I could only retrieve the path of the directory containing the Jenkinsfile.

I tried several different things like steps containing

```
script {
    println __FILE__
}
```

and

```
script { 
    scriptDir = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent
    println scriptDir
}
```

Neither of which ran (gave non-existent variable in `__FILE__` case and permission violation in the second case). I tried `"${__FILE__}"` and other variants.

I need to use the directory in a steps-sh block so I believe it needs to be in an environment item.

Now, the Jenkins job configuration gives the path to the Jenkins file, but I don't want to have to repeat that to create another environment variable at that level.

Already consulted:

- [Get absolute path of the script directory that is being processed by Job DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336502/get-absolute-path-of-the-script-directory-that-is-being-processed-by-job-dsl)
- [Get absolute path to workspace directory in Jenkins Pipeline plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934028/get-absolute-path-to-workspace-directory-in-jenkins-pipeline-plugin)
- [How can I reference the Jenkinsfile directory, with Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353963/how-can-i-reference-the-jenkinsfile-directory-with-pipeline)
- as well as many more Google hits and other sites.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Always keep your Jenkinsfile at the root of your directory. Then use 'branch' conditions (when { branch 'develop' }) to get your configuration per environment.

Comment: That doesn't work. One SCM repo contains numerous independent pipelines. I'm not going to fracture the repo into 100 different ones just so I can get an identical Jenkinsfiles in each case. It is really surprising that Jenkins Pipeline doesn't give simple access to this information.

Comment: sparse checkout?

Comment: @KevinBuchs I'm in the same situation.  Did the find a solution to you question?

Comment: @keda - no. I hope to get back to this, because there must be a way to do it, but I have to dig into the Java objects, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Found at [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022871/1225007):

```
def currentScriptPath = new File(currentBuild.rawBuild.parent.definition.scriptPath).parent
```

But it requires to approve a lot of methods.

Comment: This is the only one that works in latest Jenkins in both shared pipeline libs and in Jenkinsfiles themselves, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this method only works in the actual node context— you can't use it at the top of the Jenkinsfile to determine, for example, where to get a pod definition for kubernetes { yamlFile }.

Comment: This doesn't give me a path but only the file name (when used minus the File and parent parts, otherwise null)

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need this, you can fetch `"${JOB_URL}config.xml"` and parse `scriptPath`.

But that's not a clean solution and the request needs to be authenticated.

Comment: This looks promising. I can see the job config is properly referenced via JOB_URL. I can see the ScriptPath in the Config when viewing from an authenticated browser session. I can't http get the file from a Pipeline script, because we have authentication on our Jenkins. I don't know how to get that file from within the Pipeline groovy script. I need to determine how get at that information another way. Given the job configuration data structure, I have to believe that that information must be loaded into the JVM in memory, and with loading the right objects in Groovy, I can get at this.

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way is to put the Jenkinsfile at the root of your repository and get the value of the WORKSPACE environment variable set by Jenkins.

Given that Groovy is just basically Java, you can get the absolute path like so:

```
new File("{env.WORKSPACE}").absolutePath
```

Comment: Not in my case. We have one SCM repo with numerous Jenkinsfiles in different directories. The location of the Jenkinsfile is given when the Jenkins pipeline is created.

Comment: I would suggest restructuring your setup if you can.

Comment: @KevinBuchs how is the location given to Jenkins ??

Comment: When a pipeline job is created, with the script (Jenkinsfile) coming from SCM, you specify the script path as part of the job configuration. Screen shot: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgKA2HL-SveIgYJEJIfTqbccHIBFFw

Comment: Highly recommend making life easier for yourself and just specify Jenkinsfile without the path and then you can get the absolute path by accessing the environment variable Jenkins sets for all job {env.WORKSPACE}.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to do that cause all paths in the context of a running job are already all WORKSPACE relative.

Comment: The paths to the Jenkinsfiles are certainly relative to workspace. That doesn't mean the path is known to the pipeline Groovy code.

Comment: This answer is [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372952/5211833).

Comment: I assume most people doing this have a monorepo with multiple projects. "I would suggest **restructuring your setup** if you can." I'm not sure what you mean here. Is there a good way of loading sub-project Jenkinsfiles inside a root Jenkinsfile? That would solve this problem (finding Jenkinsfile path) for my use case.