# How to retrieve the Jenkinsfile path within the same Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently working on configuring a Jenkinsfile, and I need to obtain the path to the same Jenkinsfile within its content. I would like to use this path to perform certain operations on other files in same location.

Is there a way to retrieve the Jenkinsfile path within the same Jenkinsfile? Does Jenkins provide any environment variables or methods that can be used for this purpose?

I tried the solution from this link: [Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - how to get path to Jenkinsfile in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370984/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-how-to-get-path-to-jenkinsfile-in-use) , but it doesn't work in my case.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Workspace environment variable isnt enough ? Normaly the jenkinsfile is checked out from the scm into the workspace